# PHP reformat datetime without care about timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I have clients from different many timezone, and I need analyze their system logs which the date is printed in their local machine timezone.

example: **Mon Apr 03 00:50:15 CST 2017**

actually I don't care about their timezone, what I need to print in my application only their local time, so the printout in my apps side must be: **2017-04-03 00:50:15**.

how to convert the given date without concern about their timezone or my local server timezone or without have to set *date_default_timezone_set* in my apps? 
is there any php function to do that?

I want to avoid use string manipulation as much as possible.

thank you in advance.

BR//G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for all time-related operations, PHP expects you to set a `default` timezone (otherwise warnings are given). However, I think you're simply looking for a formatting operation.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$source = "Mon Apr 03 00:50:15 CST 2017";
$dateOb = new DateTime($source);
print_r($dateOb);
echo $dateOb->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Output:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-04-03 00:50:15.000000
    [timezone_type] => 2
    [timezone] => CST
)
2017-04-03 00:50:15
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `date_format` if you only want to format your date.

```
$date=date_create("Mon Apr 03 00:50:15 CST 2017");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: it will give you warning : PHP Warning:  date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your desired timezone to be used by all date/time functions by setting your timezone identifier using `date_default_timezone_set('parameter');`. Find the list of supported timezones at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. And then use `date_default_timezone_get();` to get your given timezone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); 
date_default_timezone_get(); 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
?>
```